# Storing user info to database after facebook registration in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, facebook-login

I am a beginner in Joomla, I want to integrate Facebook login with my website (using Joomla 3.0), I want to know how to store the user info into my database after receiving them from facebook. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

If you are using FB SDK for PHP

```
            $path = realpath('.');
        require_once($path."/facebook/fbmain.php");

         $user       = $facebook->getUser();


//      print_r($user);
//      echo "user<br/>";
//      print_r($userInfo);
//            echo "<br/>Info<br/>";
//          print_r($fqlResult);
//          foreach($fqlResult as $key=>$value){
//              print_r($value);
//              echo '<br>';
//          }
//      exit;

         if ($user){


               $fname       =   $userInfo['first_name'];
               $last_name   =   $userInfo['last_name'];
               $username    =   $userInfo['id'];
               $dob         =   date("d-m-Y",strtotime($userInfo['birthday']));
               foreach($fqlResult as $key=>$value);

               $user_email      = $value['email'];
               $profile_image   = $value['pic_square'];
               $sex             = $value['sex'];
               $city            = $value['hometown_location']['city'];
               $state           = $value['hometown_location']['state'];
               $country         = $value['hometown_location']['country'];
               $zip             = $value['hometown_location']['zip'];

                 //Then simply call model and write save db query.
                 $model = $this->getModel('Registration', 'UsersModel');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a FB authentication plugin and then have that pass off the data to the Joomla user plugin if possible. If you want to use a different user table you would need to make your own user plugin as well.  Joomla auth first authenticates (authentication plugin), then authorsises, then logs in (user plugin)